# Stylus files not compiling in Storybook, Stylus package return AST tree instead of CSS

Tags: webpack, storybook, stylus, webpack-5, stylus-loader

I'm trying to setup Storybook for the shared components library which uses stylus.

And this is what I'm getting after running `npm run build-storybook`

```
ERR! => Failed to build the preview
ERR! Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ERR! 
ERR! SyntaxError
ERR! 
ERR! (1:1) /Users/user/Work/webcomponents/src/components/button/buttonV2/buttonV2.styl Unknown word
ERR! 
ERR! > 1 | [Root]
ERR!     | ^
ERR!
```

Here is my Storybook config: (.storybook/main.ts)

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
import commonConfig from '../webpack.config'

const defaultWebpackConfig = commonConfig();

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/button.stories.ts"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  core: {
    disableTelemetry: true
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config?.module?.rules?.push(
        // manually push stylus rules, which is 3rd & 4th
        defaultWebpackConfig.module.rules[2],
        defaultWebpackConfig.module.rules[3],
    );

    config.resolve!.alias = Object.assign(
        {},
        config?.resolve?.alias,
        defaultWebpackConfig.resolve.alias,
    );
    config.resolve!.extensions!.push('.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.styl');

    return config;
  }
};
export default config;
```

Here is my Webpack config:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const isProd = argv?.mode === 'production';
    return {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/index.ts'),
        devtool: isProd ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-source-map',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            publicPath: '/build/',
            filename: 'webcomponents.js',
            library: {
                name: 'webcomponents',
                type: 'umd',
            },
        },
        target: 'web',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.styl'],
            alias: {
                '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                // add styles alias
                '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
                // import 'monaco-editor' incode will build all bundles
                // add this and monaco languages will limit outputs
                'monaco-editor': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js',
            },
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'style-loader' },
                        { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    ],
                },
                // split out global style, in order to include fixed className
                {
                    test: /\.styl$/,
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/html.styl'),
                    ],
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        { loader: 'stylus-loader' },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.styl$/,
                    exclude: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/html.styl'),
                    ],
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'style-loader' },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: '[local]-[hash:base64:16]',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'stylus-loader',
                            options: {
                                stylusOptions: {
                                    import: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/index.styl')],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                    type: 'asset',
                    parser: {
                        dataUrlCondition: {
                            maxSize: 100000,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/'),
                        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/styles/'),
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
        externals: [
            {
                ramda: 'ramda',
                lodash: {
                    commonjs: 'lodash',
                    commonjs2: 'lodash',
                    amd: 'lodash',
                    root: '_',
                },
                react: {
                    root: 'React',
                    commonjs2: 'react',
                    commonjs: 'react',
                    amd: 'react',
                },
                'react-dom': {
                    root: 'ReactDOM',
                    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
                    commonjs: 'react-dom',
                    amd: 'react-dom',
                },
                moment: 'moment',
            },
            nodeExternals({
                allowlist: [
                    'd3',
                    'material-icons',
                    'monaco-editor',
                ],
            }),
        ],
    };
};
```

And I'm able to build project successfully with Webpack, but Storybook throws this error.

I have tried to debug storybook building process and it looks like Stylus return AST tree instead of compiled CSS to css-loader

I can't understand why it works correctly directly with webpack, but it breaks when we use it in  storybook